# setup nginx to require certain conditions of a location for all but a given source IP

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm looking for a setup where I'd like to have SSL client certificates for all but one source IP.

My idea is to set

```
 ssl_verify_client optional;
```

and to add an elaborate if statement to the locations.
However I don't know how to write such an if statement.

```
  # this requires ssl client certificates for all locations
  location / {
    if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") { 
       return 403; 
    ...
  }

  # now what to write to require ssl certs except if source IP is e.g. 1.2.3.4
  location /two {
    if (?????) { 
       return 403; 
    ...
  }
```

**Edit: Additional information**

The switch [ssl_verify_client](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) with the value `optional` tells clients, that they can but don't have to send client certificates.

So by  checking the variable [$var_ssl_client_verify](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_verify) I can see whether a client certificate was presented and valid (`SUCCESS`) or not.
This rule shall be applied for all clients, that do not have a given source IP. For one specific source IP I do not want to verify client certificates.

What I need is something like

```
    if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS" and source_ip != 1.2.3.4 ) { 
       return 403; 
    }
```

**Edit 2:** I changed the title from
`setup nginx to require client certs for all but a given source IP`
to
`setup nginx to require certain conditions of a location for all but a given source IP` as what I am really struggling with has nothing to do with client certificates, but with combining if statements and filtering conditionally on the source IP address.

Comment: Using `if` inside locations doesn't work like you would expect: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple conditions aren't supported in Nginx for `if` statement. So, as a workaround and as client IP is evaluated in our usecase, the solution could be achieved similar to how it was achieved at https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/#Advanced-Configuration-Examples . Basically, the solution goes like this...

```
geo $limit {
    default 1;
    1.2.3.4 0; #please replace the example IP with the actual IP.
}

ssl_verify_client optional;
ssl_client_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;

map $limit $limit_key {
    0 "SUCCESS";
    1 $ssl_client_verify;
}

server {
    # ... other directives
    location / {
        if ( $limit_key != 'SUCCESS' ) { return 403; }
        # ... other directives
    }
}
```

Basically, we assign the value "SUCCESS" to the variable for a specific IP. For every other IP, we assign the actual value of `$ssl_client_verify`.

### Alternative Answer

```
ssl_verify_client optional;
ssl_client_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
server {
    # ... other directives
    
    # initial value of $variable is the actual value of $ssl_client_verify
    set $variable $ssl_client_verify;

    # here we re-assign $variable with "SUCCESS" for our specific IP
    # please replace 1.2.3.4 with the actual IP
    if ( $remote_addr = "1.2.3.4" ) {
        set $variable "SUCCESS";
    }

    location / {
        if ( $variable != 'SUCCESS' ) { return 403; }
        # ... other directives
    }
}
```

Comment: @gelonida Apologies for misunderstanding your question initially.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This should do the job. 

So the idea is to use `geo` for source ip adress mapping, `map` statements to create one variable, which can finally be used in an `if ( $variable != "SUCCESS") { return 403; }`

Concerning the initial misunderstanding. It made me rewrite my question in (hopefully) a less ambiguous and more generic way.

Will mark question as OK as soon as I have the opportunity to test in my environment.

In reality my scenario is a little more complicated as the ip address will be determined via the proxy protocol.

Comment: @gelonida You are right. Please see the updated answer that includes an alternative solution.

Comment: Alternative Answer is working for me. 
Didn't try so far the first one.

Comment: Glad to know it worked.